# jQuery.fn.jquery returns different version of query than bundled with jquery-rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am running into some discrepancies with query versions on different client machines. Trying to debug, I found that the jquery version returned by typing jQuery.fn.jquery in console window is different than the one I have bundled with query-rails.

bundle show command lists jquery 3.1.2

According to [Versions.md](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/VERSIONS.md) on jQuery-rails project, it should be 1.11.1.

Surprisingly, with some client machines the jQuery.fn.jquery console command returns 3.1.0 and with these client machines rails form submit with remote: true is not working. I am assuming there is some javascript error on page due to different jQuery versions.

How do I debug further? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your gem version is 3.1.2 ? in that case JQuery version would be 1.11.1

Comment: Thanks and yes, however if I type jQuery.fn.jquery in the console window in my browser on my website, I get 2.2.4 and in some cases 3.1.0